# How could I replicating the template T's argument list like make_shared<T>()

Tags: c++, templates

I noticed that make_shared() does something neat and i am wonderng how this works ... make_shared() copies and validates the argument list for the constructors of T. How does this work? How is it possible to design my own template function which copies and validates the available constructors for T?

example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Department
{
public:
        string Name;
        double Budget;
        Department(const string& name, const double& budget);
};

Department::Department(const string& n, const double& b)
        : Name(n), Budget(b)
{
        cout << Name << " : " << Budget << endl;
}

int main()
{
        shared_ptr<Department> d = make_shared<Department>("Human Resources", 1000.0);
        // shared_ptr<Department> d = make_shared<Department>(); NOT VALID
        return 0;
}
```

The above validates at compile time that make_shared(); uses the arguments const string& and const double&. How could I mimic this behaviour in my own code?

Comment: For inspiration, you could take a look at the relevant Boost header...

Comment: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Variadic-Templates-are-Funadic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done using perfect forwarding (`std::forward()`). You can read about it [here](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_07.html) (make sure you continue reading to the solution in the next page) and [here](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/cplusplus/rvalue_references_and_perfect_forwarding.html)

Answer (score 2):

There is no real validation here. `make_shared` will blindly try to
forward the arguments onto the constructor, if the arguments it has
received don't match the compiler will refuse to compile the code.

This is achieved with two things:

- variadic template arguments
- perfect forwarding

The variadic arguments make sure that `make_shared` accepts an
arbitrary length list of arguments (even the empty list) and perfect
forwarding allows those arguments to be of an arbitrary type.